# Custom domain on DurableOrchestrationClient.CreateCheckStatusResponse

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-durable-functions

Is there an elegant way to supply a custom domain to the DurableOrchestrationClient?

Our functions use the new VNet Integration to get into the VNet and only allow traffic from within the VNet. An Application Gateway is then used as the entry point to known routes. We have a custom domain associated to the IP of the app gateway so it would be preferable that the response from CreateCheckStatusResponse could accept a different domain.

The alternative isn't pretty and involves a bit of string manipulation...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/a9657173791f288d58098781b5a61a0a571bfde4/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/HttpApiHandler.cs#L831) for how the URIs are generated, it seems to be taking the host part of the request  URI. So, if you were to make calls through the App Gateway, I believe the URIs would return with the same hostname (and port if any).

Also, you could override the hostname too by constructing a new HttpRequestMessage object and pass that to `DurableOrchestrationClient.CreateCheckStatusResponse` like this

```cs
return client.CreateCheckStatusResponse(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://domain.tld"), instanceId);
```